# Can certain broadcast frequencies be used for mind control?

Tags: united-kingdom, mind-control

I was reading [an article](http://www.whale.to/b/rifat.html) last night on the communications system used by UK police. They use earpieces and there is skepticism about how they could be used to control the police or subdue them.
Is this possible?

> Microwave weapons that turn people into stressed, confused, submissive
>   zombies are being used in Britain's inner cities. Developed by the
>   communists, microwave weapons similar to microwave ovens have since
>   the 1980s, been targeted on inner city council estates. These weapons
>   transmit extremely low frequency (ELF) signals which mimic natural
>   brain waves; at the flick of a switch, all the people around these
>   microwave transmitters are turned into submissive zombies who cannot
>   think clearly, become depressed, apathetic and want to lounge around
>   all day doing nothing: the inner city malaise found on Britain's
>   streets.[1](http://www.whale.to/b/rifat.html)

Comment: Can you provide the citation you mention? Without a notable claim, this is likely to be closed.

Comment: http://www.whale.to/b/rifat.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **They use earpieces [...] they could be used to control the police or subdue them. Is 
>   this possible?**

### Control as in "Command and Control"

Obviously, police radios are used to control police officers in the sense of communicating with them to direct them to incidents.

### Subdue as in "incapacitate"

The [UK Police](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Avon-trial-reveals-limits-of-29bn-police-Tetra-network) use [Tetra](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/XU-EN/Product+Lines/Dimetra+TETRA/TETRA+Terminals/TETRA+Hand+Portables) radios.

It appears some police officers are or were [concerned](http://www.tetrawatch.net/contact/feedback.php?id=police) about the health of these systems but not that they are used for covert mind control. To be of much use, I assume any form of covert mind control would ideally need to act within minutes, rather than the weeks, months or years that these alleged health effects take to become manifest.

### Earpieces

At least some of the earpieces don't transmit radio waves, they are typically [accoustic](http://www.enforce-logic.co.uk/re03.php)

Normally wired earpieces would obvious operate at audio frequencies (20-20000 Hz) rather than at ELF or Microwave frequencies. Normally these would not transmit radio waves either.

### Studies of ELF/Microwave/Radio effects on the mind

I have not found any studies that show that radio waves can be used to control the mind. There are one or two low-quality studies in alternative journals that suggest that some brainwaves (e.g. the alpha rhythm) can be synchronised to en external source of magnetic waves - but these studies concluded that they had no effect on people's moods or thoughts. [Reference](http://journal.borderlands.com/1999/effects-of-6-10-hz-elf-on-brain-waves/)